# Unexpected behavior on code running

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

A strange behavior is occuring when running my application.

If I stop the code in debug mode before a specific line is reached, that line will be executed and everything is normal... but if i let the code run without debugging, of stop the code after, it will not run the line...

This is the code

```
if (SelectedProducts == null)
{
    Global_Image.Product_Types = null;
    Global_Image.Product_Types = new List<Prod_Product_Type>();
    return;
}
```

I'm trying to make Global_Image.Product_Types count go to 0 by making the List null and creating a new list for it... but if I stop the code in the return none of them worked... If I stop before, they run and it works fine... can someone explain this behavior?

The function is not awaited, so no sync problem here, I think... The App is in azurewebsites... 
please help

Comment: There is not reason to use those 2 lines of code. Just use `Global_Image.Product_Types.Clear();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that did the trick, but the question and problem maintains... why was the behavior different? any thought? that wasnt the first time it happened, and It wont probably be the last. and that solution wont stand ... Thanks for your answer...

Comment: I cannot repeat your issue, so can't really comment.

Comment: There is no issue in the code... the code works fine... its the behavior that doesn't makes sense, because despite the fact that that same code is working in other pages, it doesn't work in this case, and the question was intended to know if this is a known behavior with known causes... I dunno. Thanks